# AngularUI Datepicker - End Date should not be less than Start Date

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

We are using AngularUI datepicker (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for `Start and End Date`.

After integration, I was not able to select `weekend` dates as well as my end-date can be less than start-date.

I have made a plunker for the same where I was able to select weekend dates but still can not figure out how to prevent end-date not being
less than start-date. Also end-date should not be less than start-date if I click on `Today`.

Plunker URL - http://plnkr.co/edit/sWmQqHRaAJDbaEQFxzZU

Answer (score 0):

I was able to track down what was causing this to happen to the following code:

```
$scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? null : new Date();
    $scope.dateOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate;
};

$scope.toggleMin();
```

It looks like inlineOptions.minDate is there so the ternary operator sets it to null.  This effectively wipes out any minDate.  I'm thinking this should be reversed, but I'm not sure of the logic.  I do know when I comment out the code it works as it should as you can see in the plunker below:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Krr6HMM8c4E1xY4Zj6F1?p=preview

I think the ternary operator might need to be the following to fix this:

```
 $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? new Date() : null;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Select start date as 8 July and you ll be able to select 7 JUL as end date.